# Flash Advertisment Scrape in Ruby

Tags: ruby, web-scraping

I am working on a project where I need to efficiently tell if there is a flash advertisement on the current page, and if there is, I need to extract data from this.  When I look through my web inspector, the actual advertisement shows up in the XHR location, and the overall layout for each of these pages is the same, so I know that if there is an advertisement, it will show up here.  Is there an easy way to tell if there is an advertisement certain page or not? Thanks.  Also I am doing this in ruby.

Comment: You can probably find out if there's a Flash object on the page, but I don't see how you could automatically determine if it's an ad or something else.

Comment: From what I am seeing, this is the only XHR element that comes up, so if there is an add it is the only one, and if there isn't there are no XHR elements, so if there is a way to check for only these I could easily determine if it was an add or not.